# Clicking on a link changes the text layout in the Stacks Editor

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, stacks-editor, newline

Clicking on a link changes the text layout in the Stacks Editor. Example:

[image]

Tested with Chrome + Windows 10.

It doesn't happen in the Markdown-only or Markdown+preview views. It only happens when there are full URLs in the body text.

Comment: I assume this only happens in the rich-text view of the Stacks editor (i.e. it doesn't happen in the Markdown-only or Markdown+preview views)? ...Also, does this only happen when there are full URLs in the body text, or does it also occur if you click in the middle of a long word in a link that normally wraps to the next line?

Comment: @V2Blast It doesn't happen in the Markdown-only or Markdown+preview views). It only happens when there are full URLs in the body text.